# Can budget lines be discontinuous?

Tags: microeconomics, optimization

It's been awhile since I've taken introductory microeconomics. I read [budget lines can be discontinuous](https://books.google.com/books?id=xeg8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=should+budget+lines+be+continuous&source=bl&ots=vhO9gmehqA&sig=kIXEcrjw99zsCW5CddRnEi5LzFM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbmLWy7fvKAhWC3KYKHQpAAEoQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q=should%20budget%20lines%20be%20continuous&f=false) awhile ago but am suspicious as to such a concept being discussed in intro micro classes particularly calling them budget 'lines'.

---

The problem:

> Say Jill likes food and clothing. Jill has 200 to spend on food and clothing. One unit of food costs \$1 while one unit of clothing costs $2.

Budget line is 200=F+2C

> Say Jill receives an 80% discount on food but it applies up to 100 units.

New budget line is 200=0.2F+2C for 0-100 then same as old for 100 onward?

So it's discontinuous? So it's not really a budget 'line' right (though piecewise, it's a line, I guess).

Comment: What you described seems to be a kink in the line (not a discontinuity), unless you mean that if she does not receive any discount at all in case she buys more than 100 units.

Comment: @HRSE so piecewise differentiable but wholly continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the discount holds for the 100 first units of food even if she buys more than 100. Therefore the new budget line is
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
   & 200 = 0.2 F + 2C \text{ if } F < 100 \\
   & 200 = 0.2 \times 100 + F-100+2C \text{ otherwise }
   \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
which is continuous.